# Can an empty element contain child elements

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a DTD with the following element definition

```
<!ELEMENT a EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT b EMPTY>
```

Is the following XML valid based on this DTD:

```
<a><b></b></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would not be valid. An empty element can not contain any children. This includes the following types of nodes: text, element, comment, and processing instruction. The element could have attributes if they were defined.

It would be valid if you changed `EMPTY` to `ANY` or `b` in the declaration for `a`:

```
<!DOCTYPE a [
<!ELEMENT a ANY>
<!ELEMENT b EMPTY>
]>
<a><b></b></a>
```